# paypal get multiple item_number

Tags: php, paypal

I have created a paypal cart form which add multiple product for payment:

```
        <?php
        $i=1;
        foreach($p_result as $prod): 
            ?>

            <div class="image">
                <img src="images/<?php $result = $SimpleUsers->prod($prod['pid']); foreach($result as $row):echo $row['product_img'];?>" alt=""  width="97px" height="110px"/>
            </div>
            <div class="name">
                    <?php echo $row['product'].' -- ';echo $prod['month']." mesi";?>
            </div>
                     <div class="price"> 
                <?php echo "N. licenze:".$prod['quantity'];?>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                Price: <?php echo $row['price']*$prod['month']*$prod['quantity'];?>0€
            </div>

            <div class="btn">
                <form action='<?php echo $paypal_url; ?>' method='post' name='cart'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='business' value='<?php echo $paypal_id;?>'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_cart'> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">

                     <input type="hidden" name="quantity_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $prod['quantity']; ?>">
                    <input type='hidden' name='item_name_<?php echo $i; ?>' value='<?php echo $row['product'];?>'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='item_number_<?php echo $i; ?>' value='<?php echo $prod['pid'];?>'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='amount_<?php echo $i; ?>' value='<?php echo $row['price']*$prod['month'];endforeach; ?>'>
<?php $i++; ?>
                    <input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='EUR'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='handling' value='0'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://www.example.com/paypal/cancel.php'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://www.example.com/paypal/success.php'>

            <?php

      endforeach;  
        ?>
```

But on success.php page, I get all the variables, except item_number which is void

**Success.php**(part where I get variables)

```
$uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
$username=$_SESSION['username'];

$item_no = $_GET['item_number']; 
$item_transaction = $_GET['tx'];
$item_price = $_GET['amt'];
$item_currency = $_GET['cc'];
```

How I can get item_number variable?

Comment: The method on the form is POST but you are trying to access the item_no with $_GET

Comment: @Hexana I also tryed with POST but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the array in input name to get the multiple values

```
<input type='hidden' name='item_number[]' value='<?php echo $prod['pid'];?>'>
```

You can get the values using

```
print_r($_GET['item_number']) //You will get a array of item number
```

Comment: I tryed to print the array, but I get nothing, how do you print it?

Answer (score 1):

Well when you're naming it in the form you're usinh

```
'item_number_<?php echo $i; ?>' (which can look like "item_number_3")
```

but when you try to call it your using $_GET['item_number']

you would have to call $_GET['item_number_2'] with the way you're naming it.

Hope that shed some light on it, for you.

edit ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

If I were you I would change

```
<input type='hidden' name='item_number_<?php echo $i; ?>' value='<?php echo $prod['pid'];?>'>
```

to

```
<input type='hidden' name='item_number' value='<?php echo $prod['pid'];?>'>
```

and you call to $_GET['item_number'] should work fine.

Comment: I tried your solution , but it seems that there is a different problem